# Como criar array dinamicamente?

Tags: php, array

Gostaria de criar um *array* dinamicamente, tentei desta forma:

```
$zt = array();
    $zt = ($p_p[0] => $_p_p[1]);
    print_r($zt);
```

`$p_p` é um *array*, onde o índice 0 é o nome, e o índice 1 é o valor, 2 nome, 3 valor..

`$p_p` está configurado assim, mas infelizmente dá erro na linha `$zt`:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>'

Se eu fizer assim:

```
$zt = ($p_p[0]);
```

não dá erro, mas o índice é "0", eu precisava que fosse de fato o nome, já que vou passar este *array* `$zt` por `POST` como se fossem campos de um formulário.

Comment: Olha, achei a solução, mas não achei lógico isso. Eu declarei como array $zt, assim: `$zt = array();`, então eu esperava que o que $zt recebe-se se comporta-se como array, mas eu precisei alterar para isso: `array($p_p[0] => $_p_p[1]);`, ou seja, informei que era array(novamente) o que coloquei ali dentro.

Comment: Você precisou declarar novamente que o `$zt` é um array porque você estã **sobrescrevendo** a variável `$zt`.

Comment: perfeito! valeu

Answer (score 7):

Pelo que entendi você quer que `$p_p[0]` seja a key e `$p_p[1]` o value, então:

```
$zt = array();
$zt[$p_p[0]] = $p_p[1];
print_r($zt);
```

Comment: Luiz, agradeço pela resposta, não sabia que um índice podia receber um valor dessa forma!

Answer (score 2):

Se quiseres criar uma array simples (não associativa):

```
$zt = array();
$zt[] = $p_p[0] => $_p_p[1];
```

Se quiseres criar uma array associativa

```
$zt = array();
$zt[$p_p[0]] = $p_p[0] => $_p_p[1];
```

A diferença é que uma atribui o index automaticamente (numérico) e a segunda variante pode ter um index atribuído (string).