# Criação de elementos de array dinamicamente

Tags: php

O formulário abaixo contido em uma pagina `a.php` submete para uma pagina `b.php`.

```
<form method="post" action="b.php">
   <select name="zzz" id="zzz">
    <option value="id1" label="aaa">aaa</option>
    ..................
    ..................
```

Na pagina `b.php` tenho o seguinte código criado manualmente que me retorna o label do option selecionado da pagina `a.php`, eu disse o label e não o value.

```
<?php

  $options = array();

  $options["id1"] = "aaa";
  $options["id2"] = "bbb";
  $options["id3"] = "ccc";

  $label = $options[$_POST['zzz']];

  echo $label;
```

Tem como criar essas linhas

```
 $options["id1"] = "aaa";
 $options["id2"] = "bbb";
 $options["id3"] = "ccc";
```

dinamicamente a partir de um select sendo id1, id2 .... e aaa, bbb ... os valores constantes na tabela do banco de dados.

Será que existe alguma forma de criar essas linhas e que funcionem como o manualmente criado? Ou seja, em vez de digitar no codigo `id1 = "aaa"` fazer algo como `$row["id"] = "$row["xxx"]`

Comment: Isso? https://repl.it/J8L2/1

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54561/14262

Comment: Ou ainda, https://repl.it/J8L2/3 não entendi bem sua pergunta Leo, mas é esse o caminho

Comment: Eu sugeriria criar as opções usando a mesma fonte de dados que gera os <option>, de forma a atualizar os dados em um lugar só.

Comment: Não entendi bem. Você quer montar os options a partir de dados do banco? É isso?

Comment: @MarceloBoni, não fiz o comentário no sentido de denegrir, como pode ter sido interpretado pelos comentários que foram removidos, acho que me expressei mau. Só quis dizer que se não entendeu a pergunta poderia ter pedido simplesmente mais informações e depois indicar relacionadas. Mesmo pq você faz parte das pessoas que estimo nesse site!

Comment: downvoto é facil dar, dificil é explicar o porque do downvoto dado. Digno de pena esse tipo de comportamento. Não acrescenta nada de util ao site ou a quem fez a pergunta

Comment: So esclarecendo, em nenhum momento dei downvote na sua pergunta, mas ainda assim achei um pouco confusa do jeito que foi posta. Não consegui entender o seu intuito, realmente Leo... Talvez se explicasse qual foi a sua dificuldade inicial....

Comment: @MarceloBoni consegui uma solução, veja a resposta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apesar dos downvotos, fiz questão de reabrir este post e mostrar uma solução.

**Na pagina** `a.php` cria-se o arquivo `optionsArray.php`

```
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "Usuario";
$senha = "SENHA";
$dbname = "NOME_DB";

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);


$query = "SELECT id_regional, regional FROM t_regional ORDER BY regional";
$resultado=$mysqli->query($query);


$filename="optionsArray.php";

if (!file_exists($filename)) {

    $linhas="";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){

    $linhas .= "\n".'$options["'.$row['id_regional'].'"] = "'.$row['regional'].'";';

    }

    $linhas ="<?php \n".$linhas."\n ?>";

    file_put_contents($filename, $linhas);

}
```

**Na pagina `b.php`** inclua o arquivo `optionsArray.php` criado na pagina `a.php`

```
$options = array();

include_once("optionsArray.php");

$label = $options[$_POST['cbx_regional']];

echo $label;
```

**As duas páginas acima poderiam se fundir em uma só sem problemas.**

> Pergunta: o porque de querer criar esse arquivo dinamicamente?

**Resposta:** A resposta do Anderson Carlos Woss é certamente a mais obvia.

Porém não sei se eu entendi bem o comentário na resposta aceita desse post [target HTML option label instead of its value in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411463/target-html-option-label-instead-of-its-value-in-php) que diz (tradução Google) <sub>"Ok, isso funciona de certa forma. MAS, sobre se existem 100 opções de opções na página? Tenho que adicionar $ options ["music / three"] = "somename"; $ Options ["music / four"] = "somename"; Para cada um? Ou há outra maneira de fazer isso?"</sub>.

**Esse o motivo da pergunta e esse o motivo da minha resposta.**

Resumo da opera: A utilidade disso só o americano poderia explicar :)

> OBS: Não está claro de onde surgiriam essas informações, mas creio que sejam de um banco de dados.

Comment: Geralmente quando usa-se `select`, o atributo `value` recebe o valor da coluna `id` e o `label` um valor relacionado ao registro que é legível à humanos (por exemplo: nome). Então no arquivo `b.php`, basta fazer a busca no banco de dados pelo `id` e verificar qual é respectivo nome.

Answer (score 2):

Supondo que temos a tabela `browsers` no banco de dados:

```
id | name
---+------------------
1  + Google Chrome
---+------------------
2  + Firefox
---+------------------
3  + Opera
---+------------------
4  + Safari
---+------------------
5  + Internet Explorer
---+------------------
```

Podemos gerar o seguinte HTML com PHP:

```
<?php

//...

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `browsers`");

echo "<select name='browser'>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<option value='{$row['id']}' label='{$row['name']}'>{$row['name']}</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
```

A saída HTML será:

```
<select name='browser'>
    <option value='1' label='Google Chrome'>Google Chrome</option>
    <option value='2' label='Firefox'>Firefox</option>
    <option value='3' label='Opera'>Opera</option>
    <option value='4' label='Safari'>Safari</option>
    <option value='5' label='Internet Explorer'>Internet Explorer</option>
</select>
```

Quando o formulário for submetido, no PHP você pode recuperar o valor do atributo `value` selecionado. Este valor é o `id` do registro selecionado da tabela `browsers`, então, para obter o nome do navegador selecionado, basta selecionar o respectivo registro do banco:

```
<?php

// ...

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `browsers` WHERE `id` = ?")) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $_POST["browser"]);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $name);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    echo "O navegador selecionado foi: ", $name;

}
```

O código completo testado foi:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="browser">
        <?php

            $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sopt");

            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `browsers`");

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "<option value='{$row['id']}' label='{$row['name']}'>{$row['name']}</option>";
            }

        ?>
    </select>
    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>

<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `browsers` WHERE `id` = ?")) {

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $_POST["browser"]);

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $name);

        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

        echo "O navegador selecionado foi: ", $name;

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: A sua resposta é certamente a mais obvia. Não sei se eu entendi o comentário na resposta aceita desse post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411463/target-html-option-label-instead-of-its-value-in-php que diz  okay this works in a way. BUT how about if there are 100's of options on the page? do I have to add $options["music/three"] = "somename"; $options["music/four"] = "somename"; for every single one? Or is there another way to do this ? Diante disso que eu quis achar uma solução para a minha pergunta.

Comment: Essa é a questão. Você não precisa definir essas variáveis. Elas estão disponíveis no banco de dados, basta acessá-la, independente de quantos registros são.

Comment: Mas o americano não quer relacionar todas elas?

Comment: Se os dados do `select` vem do banco de dados, esta é a solução. Se não vierem, simplesmente não faz sentido esta relação com o `label`. O valor que será utilizado deverá estar sempre em `value`. No máximo é possível a criação desta relação com JavaScript, mas isso é no lado do cliente.